# CouchDB doesn't hash admin password on restart

Tags: couchdb, bitnami

The docs and `local.ini` comments say that CouchDB would hash the admin passwords on restart. However, I've restarted the db several times now and the passwords are still unhashed in plain text. What could be the reasons for that? I'm running the Bitnami CouchDB version if that makes any difference.

Comment: Which version of CouchDB? 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: 3.0.0-2-r08 (https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/couchdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because the `local.ini` is not owned by the CouchDB user.

If the `local.ini` is for example owned by root then the CouchDB process can't write to it because it lacks permission.

Please check who owns the file with `ls -l /opt/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini`

If the `local.ini` is not owned by the same owner than CouchDB try to change its owner with:

`sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /opt/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini`

After changing the user restart CouchDB.

**Note**
Your path to the `local.ini` or your CouchDB user might be different than in my answer and you might need to change this according to your configuration.

To find who owns your CouchDB process you can use `ps -aux | grep couchdb`

Comment: Bitnami automatically installs one user account called 'bitnami' during deployment. That's the one I am using right now. The access rights for `local.ini` are `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4025 Apr 29 12:13 local.ini`. What do you mean with "not owned by the CouchDB user"?

Comment: With CouchDB user is meant the Linux user who owns the CouchDB process. This process currently can't update the local.ini because it does not have admin rights. Try to execute the chown command from my answer and restart the server. If this does not work you need to figure out what user the CouchDB is. For this you could try ps -aux | grep couchdb

Comment: Updating the access rights solved the problem. Is it normal that you have to give CouchDB access rights for this file or did they mess up something with their image? They haven't mentioned this anywhere in their docs and it's also not mentioned in the CouchDB docs.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really answer if this is normal or if it was messed up by the install.

Comment: I contacted them and it was a misconfiguration in their image. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

I just wanted to let you know that we released a new version of CouchDB (3.0.0-6) including the fix on ini-file so you shouldn't experience this issue anymore with this new version.

It could take some days to be published in all the marketplaces.

Thanks so much for reporting this issue!